# Does IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation performs automatic userinfo instrospection?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, core-authentication

I am using Identity server to protect my API.
I have defined the ApiResource as this:

```
return new List<ApiResource> 
        {
            new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "phone.api",
                ApiSecrets={new Secret("secret1".Sha256())},
                Scopes =
                {
                    new Scope()
                    {
                        Name = "phone.api.full_access",
                        DisplayName = "Full access to API"

                    },
                     new Scope
                    {
                        Name = "phone.api.write",
                        DisplayName = "Write and read access to API"
                    },
                    new Scope
                    {
                        Name = "phone.api.read",
                        DisplayName = "Read only access to API"
                    }
                }
                ,UserClaims=new List<string>()
                {
                    "roles",
                   // ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth
                }
            },
```

And a test user like this:

```
new TestUser
{
   SubjectId = "1",
   Username = "Billy Admin",
   Password = "password",
   Claims = new List<Claim>()  
   {
      new Claim("roles", "phone.api.admin"),
       new Claim(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth,new DateTime(1900,10,10).ToString())
   }
 }
```

The api is protected with the following code:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Config.AUTHAUTHORITY; //"http://localhost:4000";
                options.ApiName = "phone.api";
                options.ApiSecret = "secret1";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });
```

I have the question if when a client+ access_token (not cotaining the claim 'ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth' , the API will automatically call the user info endpoint in the authority server to get the extra claims are needed.
The reason I need the extra claims are fore cheking some policies like:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
     options.AddPolicy("Only21", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
} );
```

My tests shows me that it is not calling the userinfo endpoint, and I want to know why. Should I call it in my own `AuthorizationHandler<MinimumAgeRequirement>`?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is for the claims to always be included in the token so that you can circumvent the need to callback to UserInfo endpoint. Just set `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken` to true in the client configuration.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius yes that could be a possibility, but I want to know if the package will go for the claims automatically.

Comment: Ok cool, it doesn't do that by looking at the source code (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/blob/8181a5b4c48b3e5e9318698fbfd110c0e7c01990/src/IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.cs#L63) .Looks like if you set `SupportsIntrospection` to true then it calls to `context.AuthenticateAsync(introspectionScheme)` but nowhere the introspection scheme is defined so I would imagine that to do nothing.

Comment: Since the API (i.e. the scope) is known to require the given claim I'd configure that scope to include the dob claim on the IDP side and thus it will always be available when calling said API. If I was you I'd be looking to keep IDP round trips to a minimum.

Comment: Oks!! How the package does the validation? It does a rountrip to the authority server???

Comment: How the options.Authority ="http://localhost:4000"; is being used ? @VidmantasBlazevicius

Comment: @Badulake it's the authority URL to validate the Issuer of the JWT. So basically by default the authentication middleware retrieves discovery document from the authority and then retrieves the keys that authority uses to sign the tokens. Then it uses asymetric encryption to ensure that the token has been signed by the expected issuer.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius aham, so it connects to te authority. Do you understand why it does not perform token introspection? I check the code and I think it is doing it somehow

Comment: I don't know, it's not the `AccessTokenValidation` package that performs this token validation. The package just adds the default `JwtBearer` scheme that comes with ASP.Net Core Security. Probably because introspection is very much optional and in general quite complex flow because it is an API in itself so you need authenticate which could be different based on IdentityProdiver. Discovery document is just an open URL on other hand.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius but if you see the line options.ApiSecret = "secret1"; the AddIdentityServerAuthentication allows you to provide a secret , so i understand that it is using it somehow to perform the introspection. Don't you think so?

Comment: Sorry this is actually outside of what I know for sure. What you’re saying absolutely makes sense though, let me know if you figure out the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Badulake's question is an interesting one: how do you manage API claims in an OAuth Architecture in a manner that actually works best for the API?

It is not just an OAuth technology question - it is more of an API extensibility design question. I have found that managing claims data in the API works best, and it is common to use claims caching to make this perform well.

- [OAuth 2.0 API Extensible Architecture](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/)

Out of interest, here is a .Net code sample that implements the above architecture:

- [.Net Core API Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore)

Recently I've been doing some AWS Serverless APIs and it was interesting to find that the AWS API Gateway also uses this type of approach.